# What is the directory of ActionScript 3.0 classes files?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash, directory

Im trying to find transformGestureEvent class file on my windows, have looked through Adobe Flash CC folder and also appData but couldnt find it.

Answer (score 0):

[TransformGestureEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TransformGestureEvent.html) is part of the built-in classes of Flash Player, AIR and Flash Lite.
You can find it on the package: flash.events

Comment: So what is its directory on my windows? I want to have access to the class file directly, whether it is built-in or separate. There must be a file placed somewhere including it or representing it.